# Using SeparatedListAdapter for ListView crashes on Android 2.1 but works with 2.2

Tags: android, listview, android-2.2-froyo, listadapter, simpleadapter

I am using SeparatedListAdapter as written by [Jeff Sharkey](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) . I originally started developing this application on Nexus One, where I have gotten it to work exactly as intended.  Now I am moving on testing certain parts, and my application is crashing on all these other phones that are running Android 2.1 .  My project Build Target is 2.1-update1 same as all these phones.

Here is the LogCat for the error

```
01-21 18:24:01.486: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.bindView(SimpleAdapter.java:171)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.createViewFromResource(SimpleAdapter.java:138)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.SimpleAdapter.getView(SimpleAdapter.java:116)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at com.hitpost.GamesList$SeparatedListAdapter.getView(GamesList.java:347)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1274)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1668)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:637)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1224)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1511)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1113)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:900)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:6830)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:996)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-21 18:24:01.588: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4615):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The relevant part of my code that is referenced by the logcat

```
     @Override  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        int sectionnum = 0;  
        for(Object section : this.sections.keySet()) {  
            Adapter adapter = sections.get(section);  
            int size = adapter.getCount() + 1;  
  
            
            // check if position inside this section  
            if(position == 0) 
                return headers.getView(sectionnum, convertView, parent);  
            if(position < size) {
                //View row = convertView;
                ScoreViewHolder viewHolder;
                HashMap<String,Object> map = (HashMap<String,Object>) adapter.getItem(position - 1);
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.league_list_item, null);
                    viewHolder = new ScoreViewHolder();
                    viewHolder.row = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ListItem);
                    viewHolder.checkinImage = (ImageView) viewHolder.row.findViewById(R.id.CheckinLeagueImage);
                    viewHolder.score1 = (TextView) viewHolder.row.findViewById(R.id.Team1Score);
                    viewHolder.score2 = (TextView) viewHolder.row.findViewById(R.id.Team2Score);
                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                } else {
                    viewHolder = (ScoreViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                if ((Integer) map.get("position") % 2 == 1)
                    viewHolder.row.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                else
                    viewHolder.row.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                
                if (map.get("gamestatus").equals("Final")) {
                    viewHolder.gameFinal();
                } else if (map.get("gamestatus").equals("In-Progress")) {
                    viewHolder.gameInProgress();
                } else if (map.get("gamestatus").equals("Pre-Game")) {
                    viewHolder.gameFinal();
                }
                viewHolder.row.setOnClickListener(new GameItemListener((String)map.get("id"), 
                        map.get("team2Name") + " " +
                        map.get("team2Score") + " @ " +
                        map.get("team1Name") + " " +
                        map.get("team1Score")                               
                ));
                return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);                      
            }
            
            // otherwise jump into next section  
            position -= size;  
            sectionnum++;  
        }  
        return null;  
    }
```

With the error coming on "return adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView, parent);"

Having spent a fair amount on StackOverflow, I know that its very hard to understand what is going, here is a summary. The ListView displays a list of scores for sports, so each item consists of 2 team names, 2 scores and an icon.

Would appreciate any hints. I have tried looking though the code of SimpleAdapter to figure out what is causing the error but can't figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured this out, and am responding to possibly help fellow Android developers.

The problem is that I was trying to make SeparatedListAdapter getView to do things that the underlying adapter is supposed to be taking care of. I called my adapter a SectionAdapter which extends SimpleAdapter, where I manipulate my view elements as I need to.  When I add a section like this

`adapter.addSection(currentGameDate, new SectionAdapter(mContext, mActivity, currentGameDateSubset, R.layout.league_list_item, keyNames, keyIds));`

Hope that helps.